# How to refuse adb on released Android App?

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

guys.
I want to refuse adb on released Android App, because I want to improved security on my App.
If I can make it, my App will be protected by apk extraction or reverse engineering.

Could you please show me any methods?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

First, adb doesn't work on apps.  It's an app of its own, and its just a shell that can be connected to from the external PC. So it has nothing to do with your app, the idea of your app "refusing adb" makes no sense because adb doesn't interact with your app at all.

Secondly, even if you could turn off adb-  it would give you zero protection.  You don't need it for apk extraction.  I can think of a dozen other ways to do it off the top of my head, including any backup utility ever written, using an emulator, and just installing it to SD card.

Third-  everyone needs to stop worrying about reverse engineering.  Nobody cares about your app.  It isn't special.  You aren't writing algorithms that have never been invented before.  There's nothing in your app a moderately talented engineer couldn't replicate without a single line of code just by seeing what your app does.  And he'd probably do it quicker than you did, because it's always quicker to copy ideas than to come up with them the first time.  Instead, worry about improving your app to continue to make it better for users.  Do that, and your users will stick using your software.  Waste your time and resources worrying about unimportant long shots and you're giving your competition an opportunity to pass you.